# What is the order of operations with this function call?

Tags: php

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    static function test()
    {
        echo "Victor";
    }

    static function result()
    {
        echo "My name is ".self::test();
    }
}

MyClass::result();

?>
```

I'm confused why `self::test()` is executed before the rest of the command or the other way around. Thanks in advance for the comments.

Comment: Have you tried it? What results do you get when you run this code?

Comment: @liquorvicar: Actually had the typo. I'm just confused why.

Comment: define *command*, do you mean the `echo` or the `MyClass::result();` statement?

Comment: Isn't it obvious, that test() needs to be executed before result() can print that string?

Comment: @Niko: Always thought the code executes from left to right or BEDMAS if there's math involved.

Comment: @Yoshi: `MyClass::result();` statement, which includes the `echo` command.

Comment: It may look different if you `return` the value from `test` rather than `echo` it.

Comment: @stanigator With function calls and string concatenation, code executes from the inside to the outside: `func1(func2(func3())); ` func3, then func2, then func1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because to get string that needs to be echoed out needs to be "prepared". so before output it needs to know what's the return value of it. it executes first and it's result is included in string. Actually, `self::test();` does not return value, but echoes out some text.

Comment: You got a link for that reasoning? Or is it possibly documented in echo manual already in php.net?

Comment: > void echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )

> Outputs all parameters.

(c) php.net

What you try to do is the same as `void echo ( Myclass::test())` that's why it's executed first.

Comment: @stanigator: You are performing string concatenation `x . y`. To do this, PHP needs to evaluate the expressions `x` and `y`. `x` is just a string literal, so it has the value immediately. But `y` is a function call, so it has to be executed and its *return value* (if there was any) is appended to `x`. Then the result of the concatenation is `echo`ed (`echo x . y`). Since `test()` itself contains an `echo`, you will see this value first.